# LibGdx - Move Sprite in the direction of another

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, direction, jbox2d

I'm kind new to LibGdx and I'm still learning. I'm working on a small game project to learn this nice framework. However, I'm having some issues with my game. My game is a top down shooter. There is a human character(space marine) that has to shoot an alien, which will be always moving in his direction until it  dies. My code doesn't have any bullets yet.I was able to make the shooter rotate in the direction of the cursor, as well, the alien rotate in the direction of the shooter, but I can't make the alien move in his direction. I'm pretty sure that my method that does that is completely wrong. I've tried a lot to fix it , but I can't get it fixed ! I appreciate your attention guys !
You can find the full code of the main class here:
 https://github.com/Igor-Lopes/LibGdx/blob/master/Splash.java#L125

```
public void moveAlien() {
    float mX = 0;
    float mY = 0;
    int velocity = 50;
    vAlien = new Vector2(-1 * (float) Math.sin(Alienbody.getAngle()) * velocity,
            (float) Math.cos(Alienbody.getAngle() * velocity));

    mX = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(spacemarine.getRotation()));
    mY = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(spacemarine.getRotation()));

    vAlien.x = mX;
    vAlien.y = mY;
    if (vAlien.len() > 0) {
        vAlien = vAlien.nor();
    }
    vAlien.x = vAlien.x * velocity;
    vAlien.y = vAlien.y * velocity;
    vAlien.x += vAlien.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    vAlien.y += vAlien.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}

public float rotateMarine() {
    float angle = 0;
    float mouseX = 0;
    float mouseY = 0;
    mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
    mouseY = 677 - Gdx.input.getY();
    angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(mouseX - spacemarine.getX(),
            mouseY - spacemarine.getY()));
    if (angle < 0)
        angle += 360;
    spacemarine.setRotation(angle * -1);
    return angle;
}

public float rotateAlien(Sprite s, float posX, float posY) {
    float angle = 0;
    float mouseX = 0;
    float mouseY = 0;
    mouseX = posX;
    mouseY = posY;
    angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(mouseX - s.getX(), mouseY - s.getY()));
    if (angle < 0)
        angle += 360;
    s.setRotation(angle * -1);
    return angle;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    float angle;
    moveAlien();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);
    angle = rotateMarine();
    rotateAlien(alien, spacemarine.getX(),
            spacemarine.getY());
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) == true
            && spacemarine.getY() < 560) {
        Marinebody.setTransform(spacemarine.getX(), spacemarine.getY() + 4,
                angle);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) == true
            && spacemarine.getY() > 0) {
        Marinebody.setTransform(spacemarine.getX(), spacemarine.getY() - 4,
                angle);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) == true
            && spacemarine.getX() < 920) {
        Marinebody.setTransform(spacemarine.getX() + 4, spacemarine.getY(),
                angle);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) == true
            & spacemarine.getX() > 8) {
        Marinebody.setTransform(spacemarine.getX() - 4, spacemarine.getY(),
                angle);
    }
    alien.setPosition(Alienbody.getPosition().x, Alienbody.getPosition().y);
    spacemarine.setPosition(Marinebody.getPosition().x, Marinebody.getPosition().y);
    batch.begin();
    spacemarine.draw(batch);
    alien.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
    // stage.act();
    // stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Box2D? If thats the case, then you should not set the positions of the `Body`s directly, but let the physics engine (Box2D) handle it. That means you should use forces and impulses to move the `Body`s.

Comment: Let's say that I'm trying to use Box2d and I'm new to it , so I didn't get it working,  moving the sprite with physics. Since it's a top down shooter I'm using 0 as gravity.

Comment: As you just started using Libgdx, i suggest you to start with less complex games, without using Box2D. Anyways, the (IMHO) best way to learn Box2D is http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/. The examples are in C++ as much as i remember, but the theory is the same and you should be able to do the same things with the jBox2D wrapper.

Comment: It's an assignment so I can't skip it. But thank you for your suggestion though! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Depending on how much time you have for your assignment, you could learn libgdx by creating smaller projects before starting to create the topdown shooter with Box2D. If there is not enough time for that, you should at least read all relevant parts of the libgdx wiki to get some understanding of the Framework. Also, think about the structure you want to use, if you don't organize your code, you will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the solution for awhile, but I forgot to post. Here's the method to move a list of enemies towards the player.

```
public void moveAlien() {

    for (Aliens a : aliens) { //List of Aliens (Enemy)
        Sprite s = a.getSprite(); //Get current enemy's sprite
        float targetX = spacemarine.getX(); //Player's X
        float targetY = spacemarine.getY(); //Player's Y
        float spriteX = s.getX(); //Enemy's X
        float spriteY = s.getY(); //Enemy's Y
        float x2 = s.getX(); //Enemy's new X
        float y2 = s.getY(); //Enemy's new Y
        float angle; // We use a triangle to calculate the new trajectory
            angle = (float) Math
                    .atan2(targetY - spriteY, targetX - spriteX);
            x2 += (float) Math.cos(angle) * 125
                    * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            y2 += (float) Math.sin(angle) * 125
                    * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            s.setPosition(x2, y2); //Set enemy's new positions.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points yet to add a "comment", and I'm not sure if this is your problem, but one definite bug is doing "Y += X" in the your moveAlien method on the line: vAlien.y += vAlien.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();